# Which test fixture will run after executed all test case in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testcase

I am writing the test case in python. I need to delete the folders after completed the all the test cases, which `test fixture` can be used to run after completing every thing. So that I could perform clean up operation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should keep the cleanup codes inside tearDownClass(). Even if exception occurs in any of the test method or in the setupClass(), tearDownClass() will work.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass

Answer (score 0):

After all the tests have run the final tearDownClass and tearDownModule are run.